# Pulling ListBox Data, Text and HTMLrange as Email Body

Tags: excel, vba

So I will try and be as clear as possible.

I am trying to make a macro that will populate and email with the following things: 
Values from Listboxes
Writing for the main message
and a Table of values (which I've currently got being populated as a HTML body.

For example, I would like the email body to look as follows:

"Dear" [Name from preselected listbox]
"In order that we compile the latest update for the NAV please can you arrange the following information to be provided for" [The date]
[LIST THROUGH HTML]
"Please can you provide this information by the folowinf date"/....

I've currently got the list being pulled through correctly, but that has then stopped the vba body being entered. Therefore, the following code only pulls through the list.

```
Dim Addressee As String, SenRan As Range ' Define the receipient as words
Addressee = Application.VLookup(SourceLiBo.Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:B1000"), 2, False) 'finds the email address for chosen name

Set SenRan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assets").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'Selects the range of assets to be emailed.


With OEmail
.To = Addressee 'Send to addressee
.Subject = "Information Request " & Format(Date, "mmmm")

.Body = "Dear " & Me.SourceLiBo & "," & Chr(10) & _
"In order that we can compile the latest update for the NAV, please can you arrange the following information to be provided for " & Format(Date, "mmmm") & ":" & Chr(10) & _
""
.HTMLBody = rangetoHTML(SenRan)

End With
```

How is the best way to go about this in order to have all the data pull through. I would set variables with the strings wanted for the body and input it through .HMTLBody, but would that also allow me to pull through th listbox values in HMTLBody

Comment: yes, `HTMLBody` will allow you to reference listbox values. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I must have mistyped something , which isn't a surprise as I have no understanding of HTML. I'll try and fuix it now

Comment: Oh - you mean if you are using the `rangeToHTML` method by Ron Bruin? It wont be as straightforward as I led you to believe. You can use the `.Body` or the `.HTMLBody` but not both at the same time as in your example.

Comment: That's the one :) That's what I figured above but wanted to check. I'm now rewriting so it all comes through the .HTMLBody

Answer (score 0):

I have now reworded it, thanks to braX explaining my errors. The code below (with the Ron Bruin Function) provides the correct answer.

```
With OEmail
.To = Addressee 'Send to addressee
.Subject = "Information Request " & Format(Date, "mmmm")
.HTMLBody = "Dear " & Me.SourceLiBo & "," & _
            "<br><br>" & _
            "In order that we can compile the latest update for the NAV, please can you arrange the following information to be provided for " & Format(Date, "mmmm") & ":" & _
            "<br><br>" & _
            rangetoHTML(SenRan) & _
            "<br><br>" & _
            "Please let us know if there are any additional purchases not reflected in the list above." & _
            "<br><br>" & _
            "Please can you provide this information no later than 10 working days from the date of this email to allow us to process all updates for delivery." & _
            "<br><br>" & _
            "Many Thanks"


End With
```